# Как получить загруженный файл на сервер?

Tags: php, формы

Есть html-форма, содержащая поле файл

```
<input type="file" name="data[file]" />
```

Как получить этот файл на сервере, если атрибут  name менять нельзя?

Comment: Что значит получить? Смотрите $_FILES, там нужная информация.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_FILES['data']['tmp_name']['file'];
```